# I've started a php program on Ubuntu can I close the SSH session?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, php

I've run a php file with this command:

```
php test.php
```

This file is doing it's thing fine.

The script however takes long, can I close the SSH session and will the php file still be running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, when you close the SSH session, it will terminate all non-forked processes, including `bash` (your shell) and the `php` processor.

If you want your programs to continue running when you disconnect, I recommend `tmux` or `screen`. These will start a forked session server which won't die when the client disconnects, and will additionally allow you to reconnect when you log back in so you can see the output of your program as if you'd never disconnected.